# How to migrate/update to newer version of Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have some xamarin.forms 1.xx( I dont know which version) project on multiple platforms Android and iOS. And I've been asked to upgrade it to the maximum available right now version of xamarin.forms. 
Therefore, I have 2 questions:

1) How to determine which version of forms I'm using right now (I'm working in Windows environment using Visual Studio 2015 ).

2) How to migrate/update to newest version of forms? (step by step, if it's possible). I have no idea how the result of that kind of operation supposed to look like, cuz I have never done anything like this before in my life. And what the best practices are?

What I've done is opened VS2015->Help->Xamarin release notes, however there was nothing about version of Forms I'm using. Also, I went to the official xamarin website and there was no guide how to do that. I also tried to look at the release notes the last Forms update and trying to find and fix differences, but my project is so big and I thought that this way doesn't seems right.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a forum. Please indicate what you've tried so far.

Comment: I disagree with @Soviut, although the question is clumsily asked it is a real Q/A, especially if you focus on the _What are the best practice?_ part. And it's worth an detailed answer because I can see many threads that only talk about the technical part on SO.

Comment: "best practices" are usually opinion-based and their vagueness leads to broad interpretation; Two concrete reasons given when closing questions. Asking for step-by-step tutorials is NOT what SO is about.

Comment: Ok. Then on which SE site would it be suitable for developers to share their experience about upgrading libraries/frameworks if not on SO?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer first the *What are the best practice regarding upgrading a Xamarin.Forms application?* first and then address your other concerns.

I recently upgraded from 1.5.1 to 2.3.2, and from my experience, this is the steps to go through:

1. Decide which version you will upgrade *from* and *to*.
2. Read the change logs for **all stabled releases** between these two versions and look for breaking changes/bugfixes. You can find the release notes on [Xamarin's website](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/) or on NuGet's website too.
   Check regularly for new releases on the Xamarin.Forms forum and check if any reported issues may affect you. Every time Xamarin makes a release, there is a thread full of comments from other developers that may have encountered issues you might be interested in.
3. Using [your favorite versioning software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git), make sure that all local changes are commited or stashed and create a new branch for your Xamarin.Forms upgrade (you don't know how long the upgrade will take and you still want to be able to send patches during the process)
4. Upgrade: Read the *Important notes* at [Xamarin.Forms 2.3.2 release notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-2.3/2.3.2-stable/), especially the *When upgrading Xamarin.Forms take care not to simply "update all" as ...* part. Remember to upgrade on your PCL project, on your iOS project and on your Android project.
5. Test your whole app on as many devices as possible and for the longest possible period before you merge your branch back into your development/master/Main branch and address the potential incompatibility issues that may have been created in your development/master/Main simultaneously.

Step 3 is very important as it will allow you to reset back to your starting point and restart if you should fail to upgrade for whatever reason.

Xamarin.Forms is moving fast so it's important that you always keep an eye on what's going on even if you don't upgrade.

**Which version am I using right now?**

You can check that in the NuGet package interface or in the `packages.json` file in your project.

Comment: In addition to this I would recommend removing your Google Support libraries as Forms has specific dependencies.  NuGet will pull the correct versions.  I would also strongly recommend backing up your project!  If you're upgrading from Forms 1.x then you'll need to be aware that Forms has grown a lot over the last year or so and some changes may need to be made to your project.